# Storing Variable Names in an Array

Tags: php, arrays

So I have a List of Variables

```
$TestData1="Hello";
$TestData2="";
$TestData3="0";
$TestData4="Yes";
$TestData5=" ";
$TestData6="No";
```

I want to make a function that will run all these variables through a filter. I  want to make this a loop that checks all the variables in one shot. I had the idea of storing the variable names in an array. This is shown below.

```
$TestArray=array("TestData1", "TestData2", "TestData3", "TestData4","TestData5","TestData6");
```

So my main question is how would I take these names in the array and run a loop that checks to see if a certain condition is met. Example below.

```
foreach ($TestArray as $Data):

   $VariableToTestConnditions="$".$Data;



endforeach;
```

I know that statement doesn't work, but it is all I could think of.  The out come of this would be if the variable value =="Yes" then is would change the original variable's value to "N/A". So after it checks all the variables, it would change $TestData4 to "N/A".

Comment: Why not store data in an array?

Comment: if you need to keep the name of the variable (eg `TestData1`), just use an associative array: `$TestArray = array("TestData1" => "Hello", "TestData2" => "", ....);`

Comment: @zerkms I need to change the original variable value.

Comment: @kennypu That does not allow me to change the original value of the variable. Thank you for the suggestion. How would I use the Name of the value as a Variable?

Comment: @KevinWeber yes it does. the question is: do you need to have all those separate variables? if not, you can just use an associative array and keep track of them there. I'll post an answer using it.

Comment: @Kevin Weber: so store original values in array as well :-S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i used echo to demo the syntax, you can use what you like

```
$TestData1="Hello";
$TestData2="";
$TestData3="0";
$TestData4="Yes";
$TestData5=" ";
$TestData6="No";

$TestArray=array("TestData1", "TestData2", "TestData3", "TestData4","TestData5","TestData6");


foreach($TestArray as $a){

echo ${$a};
 //or 
echo $$a;

}
```

Answer (score 6):

instead of having an array of the names, it would make more sense to have an associative array (key value pairs):

```
$TestArray = array(
    "TestData1" => "Hello",
    "TestData2" => "",
    "TestData3" => "0",
    "TestData4" => "Yes",
    "TestData5" => " ",
    "TestData6" => "No"
);
```

now if you wanted to test a variable:

```
foreach($TestArray as $key => $value) {
    if($VariableToTestConnditions == $value) {
        //do something 
    }
}
```

if you wanted to change the value of a testdata:

```
$TestArray["TestData1"] = "Good Bye";
```

this way is much neater and simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Use the two-dollar sign.

See PHP variable variables: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

```
foreach ($TestArray as $Data):

   $VariableToTestConnditions=$$Data;

endforeach;
```